# How to add multiple nodes to linked list in C with no head/tail pointer?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a multiple layer linked list with a patient list, each patient list points to a linked list with patients, each patient points to a linked list of doctors. I am trying to add multiple doctors, but when I try to display the doctors I get an infinite loop as if there is no next pointer pointing to NULL. If it is just one doctor, everything works fine.

I've tried multiple approaches such as setting the old node to a temporary pointer and then setting the new node to point to the temporary. My patient list linked list and patient linked list work 100%.

```
struct doctor {
char name[MAX_NAME];
struct doctor *next;
};
void addDoctor(char* patientNameInput, char* doctorNameInput)
{
struct patientList* tempList = list;   // work on a copy of 'list'
int i = 0;

struct doctor* newDoctorNode = NULL;
newDoctorNode = (struct doctor*) malloc(sizeof(struct doctor));
struct doctor* tmp = NULL;

while (tempList != NULL)
{
    while (tempList->patient->name[i] == patientNameInput[i])
    {
        if (tempList->patient->name[i] == '\0')
        {
            tempList->patient->doctors = newDoctorNode;
            newDoctorNode->next = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        tempList->patient->doctors->name[i] = doctorNameInput[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    tempList = tempList->next;
}

}
```

The function searches for the patient name and corresponding patient list linked list. When found, it adds the doctor node for the corresponding patient. If I include my old temporary pointer attempt and display the function, I'll get an infinite loop. I expect the output to be able to display more than 1 doctor with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
        tempList->patient->doctors = newDoctorNode;
        newDoctorNode->next = NULL;
```

to:

```
        newDoctorNode->next = tempList->patient->doctors;
        tempList->patient->doctors = newDoctorNode;
```

This will add the new doctor node to the front of the existing doctor list.  If you instead want to add it to the end, then you'll need to traverse the list to find the end.

Comment: This works for the most part, but when I add in two doctors all their names get linked together. 1 doctor works fine, 3 or more doctors works fine too. for example if I add  
  Bob - doctors: Paul. Then I add George - doctors: Leo. It'll display Bob - doctors: Paul, Leo. George - doctors: Paul Leo

Comment: The function now uses my old piece of code if there are no doctors. Else the function uses the code you provided.

Comment: Well one thing you should definitely do is add a `break;` to the end of the `if` that checks for the end of the name.  Without it, you will continue to look beyond the end of the name, with unpredictable results.  Once you see the end of the string, you can not look beyond it.

Comment: By the way, normally one simply uses `strcmp(str1, str2) == 0` to see if two strings are equal, rather than writing an in-line loop to do the comparison.  This makes for much simpler, and less error prone, code.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention I did add in that `break;`

Comment: Just add `#include <string.h>` to use `strcmp`.